# finding files that were modified before a certain file

Tags: linux, unix

Hello I am trying to write a unix code that will find all the files which were modified before a certain

file.

So far I have,

```
find [directory] -type f -mtime date -r [certain_file]
```

but the system return an error saying

```
find: invalid argument `date' to `-mtime'
```

I am trying to write this in one line and I just can't seem to figure out a way to specify the timestamp

of [certain_file].

How can I express

-mtime {date -r [certain_file]}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the negation of `find`'s `-newer` condition.

```
find [directory] -type f \! -newer [certain_file]
```